# Создать кнопки бота telegram посредством php

Tags: telegram-bot

Доброе утро! Я новичок в php, не планирую его углубленно изучать. Просто пришлось решить одну задачу, для бизнеса. А именно создать удобный бот telegram. Так вот у меня есть код

```
$res = message_to_telegram($text);


function message_to_telegram($text)
{

     
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TELEGRAM_TOKEN . '/sendMessage',
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'chat_id' => TELEGRAM_CHATID,
                'text' => $text,
                'reply_markup' => $keyboard,                
            ),
        )
    );
    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

так вот, не меняя этот код, можете мне подсказать как мне написать код для конопок к боту? а еще лучше если вы мне помогли бы, примером. Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо передавать массив, который содержит в себе кнопки.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup

У вас даже он объявлен keyboard
Например

```
$keyboard = [
              [
                ['text' => 'button1']
              ], 
              [
                ['text' => 'button2']
              ]
            ];
$res = message_to_telegram($text);


function message_to_telegram($text, $keyboard = [])
{

     
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TELEGRAM_TOKEN . '/sendMessage',
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'chat_id' => TELEGRAM_CHATID,
                'text' => $text,
                'reply_markup' => $keyboard,                
            ),
        )
    );
    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: Вы знаете, как раз таки я его объявлял по той же схеме написав массив. но не работает почему то... сообщение отправляет а вот кнопки нет. все что пишу в $text он отправляет на ура... но вот $keyboard  ноль реакции

Comment: и когда я добавляю $keyboard = [] метод function message_to_telegram($text, $keyboard = []) то даже $text ничего не отправляет, скрипт перестает работать

Comment: @ЮсуфШадиев какую ошибку пишет telegram? $response = curl_exec($ch);
и логируйте это в файл или выводите на экран, если вручную скрипт запускаете

Comment: вот {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}

Comment: ну в данном случае, пустой параметр text

Comment: вы же пытаетесь использовать inline клавиатуру, она вроде должна идти с текстом вместе

Comment: извиняюсь я проверил на ошибку немного не так. вот ошибка реальная. {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"}

Comment: попробуйте перевести keyboard в json, возможно оно его ожидает.Нет сейчас возможности посмотреть свои примеры(

Comment: Вариант 1: 'reply_markup' => json_decode($stringJSON) ОШИБКА Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/users/j/j584124/domains/poabsolut.ru/tellegram.php on line 103
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat_id is empty"} НО текстовые сообщения уходят

Comment: Ну там же все пишет. Вы json_decode не правильно вызвали. Потому что вам вообще надо был json_encode. $keboard = json_encode($keyboard);

Comment: Вариант 2: ``` $keyboard = [
              [
                ['text' => 'button1']
              ], 
              [
                ['text' => 'button2']
              ]
            ];
   
 $keyboard = json_decode($stringJSON);    ``` ОШИБКА {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"} Текстовые сообщения не уходят

Comment: та же самая ошибка 'reply_markup' => json_encode($stringJSON),                Warning: Missing argument 2 for message_to_telegram(),  line 85 and defined in / on line 88
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: object expected as reply markup"}

Comment: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: object expected as reply markup"}

Comment: Я в принципе так же и экспериментировал вчера и сегодня... не показывает кнопок. поэтому тут и обратился... много времени на это потратил... очень много

Comment: Ок, уберите перевод в json. И оберните свои параметры в функцию http_build_query()

Comment: Вот один из старых моих ботов, который нормально отправлял. Может поможет)
https://codeshare.io/f7uWN